# Recorrer array y generar json con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../conexion.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "select idusuario, cuenta from usuarios")) {
    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $start, $end);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $idusuario, $cuenta);
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        $result["success"] = "true";
        $result["data"]["usuarios"] = array('iduser'=>$idusuario,'cuenta'=>$cuenta);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 }
else{
echo "Statement Prepare Error";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

El problema es que solo me genera el JSON con un solo valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas re-escribiendo el valor de usuarios por cada iteracion.  La solucion es volver dicho valor a un array.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
require_once('../conexion.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "select idusuario, cuenta from usuarios")) {
    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $start, $end);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $idusuario, $cuenta);
    $result = array();
    $result["success"] = "true";
    while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){            
        $result["data"]["usuarios"][] = array('iduser'=>$idusuario,'cuenta'=>$cuenta);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 }
else{
echo "Statement Prepare Error";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, Gracias

Comment: quizá también deberías de sacar del while el $result["success"] pues no tiene caso que en cada iteración del while se sobrescriba ese valor

Comment: Correcto, ya lo hice.

Comment: @arglez35 si es una petición Ajax, ten cuidado con la parte del `else`, no deberías hacer un simple `echo` si la petición Ajax espera un JSON. Deberías hacer algo así: `$result ["error"]="Statement prepare error";` y sacar esta parte del 1er bloque del if,  poniéndola al final del todo: `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` también el cierre de la conexión debería ir antes, pues el código nunca ejecuta esa línea cuando el statement es exitoso. Son pequeños errores de lógica que suelen cometerse y que observo en tu código.

Comment: Tienes razón @A.Cedano gracias por la observación y el comentario.